# C# Dynamically Delete Relations Using LLBL

Tags: c#, asp.net, llblgenpro

Just looking for a little help concerning LLBL and deleting related entities. I am in the process of creating a common code base and am looking to reduce the dependencies of our current Data Access Layer. In doing so, I am trying to figure out a bunch of ways to generically take Entities and Entity Collections and modify/delete/create them using IEntityCollection/ IEntity.

The below will work, I was just wondering if there is a better way of doing this? I couldn't seem to find a whole lot of documentation or examples on it.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static bool DeleteAllRelations(IEntity entity)
{
    var rList = entity.GetMemberEntityCollections();
    if (rList.Count == 0)
        return false;            
    try
    {
        foreach (var ent in rList)
        {
            ent.DeleteMulti();
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Code is called by the following:

```
var cBEntity = new ContentBlockEntity(cBlockId);
if (EntityUtilities.DeleteAllRelations(cBEntity))
{
    // Related Entities Deleted
    cBEntity.Delete();
    // Redirect To Admin List
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/ContentVersionList.aspx?id=" + siteMapId,true);
} 

DisplayError("Some Error Message Concerning Delete");
```

Comment: Are you asking about cascading deletes?

Comment: Which version of LLBLGen?  Sql Server?

Comment: What about transaction atomicity?

Comment: Sorry for the delay,
I have my Database Foreign Keys setup to do Cascade.
It is llbl 2.6 and the database version is SQL 2008 R2.

Thanks again.